# Syntax Higlighter For Site

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a website. But I need to make a syntax highlighting program that Categorize commands based on what they do. For example, one group would be I/O, another one would be Control commands. And you would color the text based off of what type of command it is.  Please I need help.

```
<html>
<head>
<div class=“io”>Text goes here</div>
div.io {
color: #0A0A0A;
</head>
<!--
PREFIX = 'lang/'
SUFFIX = '.js'
-->
 <body onload="sh_highlightDocument('lang/', '.js');">

<!--
 CLASS = 'sh_java'
 PREFIX + CLASS + SUFFIX = 'lang/' + 'sh_java' + '.js'
                    = 'lang/sh_java.js'
 -->
 <pre class="sh_java">
 public class X {}
 </pre>

  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Great! Now what is your **question**? StackOverflow is a question-answer site, and you seem to have failed to include one. Please clearly indicate exactly which **specific** problem are you struggling with, in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Please specify your question. How would this look, which categories? What color should change? Text color, background color? If possible provide a code snippet!

Comment: The text colors need to change. Please help

Comment: **Which** text colours need to change? **When** should the text change colour? What colour should the text change **to**? What have you [**already tried**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to make the text change colour?

Comment: I need the I/O text change to red and the commands become green

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code above:

- You are writing your `<div>` in the `<head>` section, which is **[invalid HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element)**
- You are using curly `“ ”` quotes on your `<div>` class declaration, which won't work

In addition to this, your question is incredibly vague. There don't appear to be any 'control commands' in your question.

Having said that, it **sounds** like you're trying to turn the text in the `io` class red, and some additional content in a `control-commands` class green.

This can be done with JavaScript's **[`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)** method and **[`.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)** property as follows:

```js
function change() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('io')[0].style.color = 'red';
  document.getElementsByClassName('control-commands')[0].style.color = 'green';
}
```

```html
<div class='io'>IO</div>
<div class='control-commands'>Control Commands</div>
<br />
<button onclick="change()">Change</button>
```

Keep in mind that `.getElementsByClassName` returns a **Node List**, so you need to access the first index of that with `[0]` as above.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot Obsidian Age, your a really awesome person:)